# ASP.NET DataList.DataBind() Causes CPU increase

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding

I have a UserControl in a page where there is a DataList item and when I do a DataBind call on the item the CPU spikes about 15-20%. So every time I refresh the page the CPU usage increases until it hits the high 90%+.

I believe it is at that line shown below because when I comment it out it doesn't happen and when I uncomment it it does happen (this is consistent).

```
dataListControl.DataBind();
```

Furthermore, when I reduce the number of records returned from the query (by using top) there is no issue. The query is very simple and is shown below.

```
SELECT top 25 *
    FROM Questions Q 
    WHERE isBold=1
    ORDER BY 
    Question
```

There is no threading involved (besides asp.net's handling of things). So just a page_load method that calls a db and returns a DataTable and then that is bound to the control as shown above.

There is no custom OnItemDataBound event so there is no additional code that runs when the DataList is being bound.

Furthermore, on debugging the page using a smaller result set (top 25), I step through the code and everything looks fine. After:

```
dataListControl.DataBind();
```

it goes to the .ascx page and loops through the data list there and then goes up the chain (webform, masterpage).

The page always returns. So for even larger result sets the page actually loads and I can do other stuff. I can click on the link that redirects to the same page and the same thing happens: the page loads and CPU usage spikes another 15-20%.

This, thankfully, does not happen in production. However, when developing locally I have to manually kill the process every few minutes since the laptop slows down considerably. How can I tackle this issue?

EDIT: adding Datalist

```
<asp:DataList ID="questionDataList" runat="server" Width="100%" OnItemCommand="questionDataList_ItemCommand">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <table width="90%">
            <tr>
                <td width="70%">
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="questionCheckbox" CssClass="FormLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("isBold")!=DBNull.Value?(Eval("isBold").ToString()=="True")?"<b>" +Eval("Question")+"</b>":Eval("Question"):Eval("Question")%>' />
                    <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="questionIDHiddenField" Value='<%#Eval("Id") %>'
                        Visible="false" />
                </td>
                <td width="15%">
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="questionDeleteLinkButton" runat="server" CssClass="FormLabel"
                        CommandName="Delete" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("Id") %>' Text="Delete" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure want to delete this Question?');"></asp:LinkButton>
                </td>
                <td width="15%">
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="isQuestionBoldCheckBox" CssClass="FormLabel" runat="server" Text="Mark Bold"
                        Checked='<%#Eval("isBold").ToString()=="True"%>' OnCheckedChanged="isQuestionBoldCheckBox_CheckedChanged"
                        AutoPostBack="true"></asp:CheckBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

EDIT 2: 
This edit is removed as it turns out it wasn't true.

EDIT 3:

I put the DataList in a page by itself does the same thing. I also changed it to a repeater and I get the same thing. So it has nothing to do with it being in a UC. Codebehind is found below.

When I run the stored proc there is no spike.

I tried disabling the viewstate at the DataList level and at the page level it is still there in the html source. Not sure if there is any other level I need to disable.

Just saw this: [ViewStateMode Disabled but still getting ViewState element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2834066/viewstatemode-disabled-but-still-getting-viewstate-element)

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    question.questionID = 0;
    question.isBold = 1;
    question.question = "";

    Repeater2.DataSource = GetQuestions(question);
    Repeater2.DataBind();
}

public DataTable GetQuestions(Question question)
{
    dtContainer = new DataTable();
    try
    {
        common.SetDBProcedureName("getQuestions");
        MyParameter[] myParameter =
        {
            new MyParameter("@isBold", question.isBold),
            new MyParameter("@searchText", question.strQuestion)
        };

        common.SetProcedureParameter(myParameter);
        common.Procedure_Execute(dtContainer);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ErrorReporting.DataLayerError(ex);
    }
    return dtContainer;
}
```

EDIT 4: when I change the content of the table as shown below  in the repeater there is no issue.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater2" runat="server" EnableViewState="false">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <table width="90%">
                <td width="70%">
                    <%#Eval("Id") %>   <%#Eval("isBold").ToString()=="True"%>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server"></asp:Repeater>
        </table>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

When I add this row as shown below the issue happens, but it actually eventually goes down. It takes about 10 seconds. So it might have something to do with the viewstate as the viewstate gets significantly bigger when I add the extra row below. I kept adding rows till I got the original data list and it actually goes down after like 30 - 40 second. When I refresh the page a few times it spikes to 50% for like half a minute or so. The original datalist was in a page and I guess that had other server controls as well so it taking much longer (longer than a minute) for the spike to go down.

So what part of the page or what process keeps running in the background even after the page is served? and how can I fix this. I dont think it should take 20 seconds for the spike to come down for just a table with 200 rows.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater2" runat="server" EnableViewState="false">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <table width="90%">
            <td width="70%">
                 <%#Eval("Id") %>      <%#Eval("isBold").ToString()=="True"%>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server"></asp:Repeater>
        </table>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: have you got user controls inside the data list?

Comment: @user Just out of curiosity, how many records will the query without the TOP return?

Comment: Two questions: Is it the CPU that spikes 15-20% or the memory usage?  (A spike by definition goes up and comes back down, it looks like a spike, it is not necessarily a bad thing, it shows that your CPU is doing stuff).  If it is the memory usage that goes up that means you've got a memory leak somewhere in your code. (Yes managed code can have memory leaks).  What DB is this running against and is it on the same machine?

Comment: No UC inside the data list. There are 220 rows only. I guess it is not a spike then. It stays at that level for at least 5 mins before I shut it down myself. MSSQL and DB is local. Query is in an SP.

Comment: when you run the sproc manually do you get the same spike?

Comment: perhaps you could post the whole codebehind? I've had probs with usercontrols in lists as THBBFT mentioned but cant see anything untoward in your code

Comment: a couple ideas to test: have you tried putting the datalist directly on the page (no user control); and (random idea) have you tried caching the data and binding that? (i've also had some luck deleting and replacing controls when all else fails. not the user control necessarily, could be datalist or other controls inside.)

Comment: I wonder if this is down to the ViewState. On your DataList set the `ViewStateMode='Disabled'` see if that does anything - that's a long shot in the dark though. I would also query the code you're using to load your DataTable, if you could include that in the original question that'd be helpful.

Comment: Please see post for comments

Comment: You've got some closing tags in there but no opening ones. I take it this `common` component is properly opening and closing the database connection and implements `IDisposable`? If so then the issue may be more browser related than the codebehind. Out of interest add this to the page and set `CssClass` of the DataList/Repeater to use it: `.fixedLayout { table-layout: fixed; }` (this may make a mess of your formatting but it can be cleared up later). You can also try adding some pagination in there and limiting it to something like 5 results, see if you get the same slow down.

Comment: I use common in the entire app and it is a pretty big app. I don't use `IDisposable` interface, but I close in a finally block. It uses `SqlCommand` and loads the result into a `DataTable`. Added the css to the table in the repeater. I don't think the repeater takes a `CssClass` attribute.

Comment: You'll need to add the CssClass into whatever `table` you're producing.  If nothing else you should get a performance boost from the browser rendering the page as it doesn't have to calculate all the column widths as it loads in.

Comment: So, you are saying that fetching the data - GetQuestions(question); is fast, but calling the DataBind() method causes the spike, right? 

Can you then remove all Eval statements from the ascx file and see if this improves anything

Comment: If you check under EDIT 4 you will see that even reducing the content of the repeater there is no issue. Adding a checkbox or the other rows causes this issue.